# ¿Qué tipo de objeto es éste y cómo accedo a sus datos? [{...}]

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

```
    [{ 
        fieldname: 'image_avatar',
        originalname: 'Capture.PNG',
        encoding: '7bit',
        mimetype: 'image/png',
        destination: './uploads',
        filename: '578fc79558e6f2abb72e18fc06c79b3e',
        path: 'uploads\\578fc79558e6f2abb72e18fc06c79b3e',
        size: 23913 
    }]
```

Comment: igualmente necesito obtener sus datos de ello

Comment: Dios me abrió los ojos, [ https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json.asp]
Es un array de objetos, para acceder a el necesitas acceder a su pocisión. objeto[0].fieldname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso es un array de objetos, es decir un array que contiene varios objetos, para accederlo puedes recorrer con un ciclo for

```
for (let item of array) {
    console.log(item.atributo);
}
```

O acceder mediante su indice

```
console.log(array[0].atributo)
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp mas informacion sobre arrays en w3schools